# Capture the data and payload in a packet

Tags: protocols, packet, packet-sniffers, payload

Is it possible to view the application protocol header? If yes, then what is the idea, algorithm or which libraries are needed?
If this comes under the concept of hacking.

Unlike standard packet capture, which only reviews the information in the packet header, DPC captures and reviews the packet header as well as the data or payload the packet's carrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unlike standard packet capture, which only reviews the information in the packet header, DPC captures and reviews the packet header as well as the data or payload the packet's carrying.

Then both tcpdump and Wireshark perform "DPC", presumably meaning "Deep Packet Capture", as they look at all protocols layers, for at least some protocols (and for a *lot* of protocols, in the case of Wireshark).  They might not handle the protocols you're interested in, but there's probably *NO* software out there that handles *every* protocol.

(*This* is why I think the word "deep" is a bunch of marketing nonsense.  It doesn't actually mean anything really significant, if it just means "stuff below the transport layer".)

> Is it possible to view application protocol header?

Yes.  Many protocol analyzers support that.

> if yes. what is the idea ,algorithm or libraries.

The source code to those analyzers, which, in most cases, is proprietary.  Wireshark, however, is open source, as is tcpdump.

Comment: The sniffers as you mentioned above are all used to sniff only standard protocols.i got these results.There is some protocols in application layer.How can we get header and data in those protocols.Application protocols such as, whatsapp,viber,gmail etc.,.

Comment: By either using existing plugins for those protocols or by writing your own plugins for those protocols.

Comment: can you comment some links to refer for plugin support.

Comment: LMGTFY.  WhatsApp plugin for Wireshark: https://github.com/davidgfnet/wireshark-whatsapp Viber: nothing found Gmail: what protocols do they use other than IMAP, SMTP, and [something layered atop HTTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)?